# Graphql Update Syntax issue with App sync

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

I am not familiar with appsync's syntax with graphql. I am trying to update one of my entities using app sync. I used Amazon's option to automatically allocate resources and connect them to DynamoDB. Here is my entity:

```
type Property {
  id: ID!
  address: String!
  listedDate: AWSDate!
  notes: String
  homeType: String!
  tenantName: String!
  ownerName: String!
  leaseExpDate: AWSDate!
}
```

Inside of my mutations, I have this:

```
type Mutation {
  updateProperty(input: UpdatePropertyInput!): Property
}
```

Along with this input:

```
input UpdatePropertyInput {
  id: ID!
  address: String
  listedDate: AWSDate
  notes: String
  homeType: String
  tenantName: String
  ownerName: String
  leaseExpDate: AWSDate
}
```

Here is my attempt at the mutation to update the given property:

```
mutation updateProperty {
    updateProperty(input: UpdatePropertyInput(id: 'myID')) {
      address: String!
    }
}
```

The closest implementation that I found in the appsync's docs can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-dynamodb-resolvers.html#modifying-the-updatepost-resolver-dynamodb-updateitem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input objects are constructed using brackets like below:

```
mutation updateProperty {
    updateProperty(input: {
      id: "myID",
      address: "myAddress"
    }) {
      address
    }
}
```

Here is some additional documentation on input objects can be found here:

- https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#input-types
- https://graphql.org/graphql-js/mutations-and-input-types/

Comment: Thank you for your answer as well as some documentation!